# $P(|X - x| \leq |X - y|)$ with randvar $X$ on uniform distribution $[0,1]$ in terms of integers $x$ and $y$.

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm sorry for this basic question, but my brain doesn't want to be functional at the moment, thanks for the help.

What is the $P(|X - x| \leq  |X - y|)$ with the random variable $X$ on uniform distribution $[0,1]$ in terms of reals $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Suggest you change "integers" to "real numbers" in the title and in the question body, if you do mean reals as last sentence says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\quad\Longrightarrow\quad}$
$$
\abs{X - y}
>
\abs{X - x}
\imp
X^{2} -2Xy + y^{2} > X^{2} - 2Xx + x^{2}
\imp
2\left(x - y\right) > x^{2} - y^{2}
$$

1. ${\Large x < y}$
       
       $$
       X > {1 \over 2}\left(x + y\right)
       $$
       $$
       {\rm P}\left(\abs{X - x} \leq \abs{X - y}\right)
       \equiv
       {\rm P}_{<}\left(x, y\right)
       =
       \left\{%
       \begin{array}{ll}
       1 & \mbox{if}\quad x < -y
       \\[1mm]
       1 - {1 \over 2}\,\left(x + y\right) & \mbox{if}\quad 0 \leq x + y < 2
       \\[1mm]
       0 & \mbox{if}\quad x + y > 2\
       \end{array}\right.
       $$
2. ${\Large x = y.\quad}$ Trivial:
       $\displaystyle{{\rm P}\left(\abs{X - x} \leq \abs{X - x}\right) = 1}$
3. ${\Large x > y.\quad}$
       $\displaystyle{{\rm P}\left(\abs{X - x} \leq \abs{X - y}\right)
                      =
                      {\rm P}_{<}\left(y,x\right).\quad}$ See $1.$